# Eliminate a user who meets the condition, even though they may not meet the condition in other rows

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is (amongst other things) looking for people who are available for a shift on a certain day.

```
SELECT secud_id, secud_fname, secud_sname, user_id, user_owner, user_level, shift_start, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uq_name SEPARATOR ' ') quals 
FROM user_data 
INNER JOIN users ON user_data.secud_ulink = users.user_id 
LEFT JOIN user_quals ON users.user_id = user_quals.uq_user 
LEFT JOIN shifts ON shifts.shift_user = users.user_id 
WHERE users.user_owner = 2 
AND users.user_level= 'Personnel' 
AND (date(shifts.shift_start) <> '2016-03-16' OR date(shifts.shift_start) IS NULL) 
AND users.user_active = 1 
GROUP BY users.user_id 
ORDER BY secud_sname ASC
```

To explain the structure, users is the users main table, user_quals holds various certificates etc (and may be empty for that user, or have many entries), user_data holds assorted bits of information for the user & shifts holds the shift dates and times, locations etc (which may also have lots or none).

I'm mostly getting what I want - a list of active users with their qualifications who belong to a certain organisation (user_owner) with the user_level of Personnel who don't have a shift on that date, however they are showing up if they are found to have a shift on another date which of course meets the WHERE clause.  If they have a shift on that date, even though they may be returned in other rows, I don't want them to appear.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also address it in the `JOIN` to `shifts`, narrowing the selection from the table to only the target date:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN shifts ON shifts.shift_user = users.user_id and date(shifts.shift_start)='2016-03-16'
```

Then in your `WHERE` clause, target only the `null` records for `shift_start`:

```
WHERE shift_start IS NULL
```

*or*

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN shifts ON shifts.shift_user = users.user_id and date(shifts.shift_user) = '2016-03-16'
WHERE users.user_owner = 2 
  AND users.user_level= 'Personnel' 
  AND date(shifts.shift_start) IS NULL
  AND users.user_active = 1 
GROUP BY users.user_id 
ORDER BY secud_sname ASC
```

Comment: After a few minutes digesting spencer's awesome lesson above, yours made it make a little more sense for me, and works very nicely.  Very grateful to spencer, but have to give this on the tick.  Thanks Von Rugen.

Comment: NOTE: with the **`DATE(col) = literal`** predicate, MySQL is prevented from making use of a range scan operation on an appropriate index.  With this form, the `DATE()` function has to be evaluated for every row in the table (at least, every row in the table that isn't filtered out by some other condition). The return from the function is compared to the literal. It is possible to write a predicate that returns an equivalent result, but that allows MySQL to make effective use of a suitable index.

Comment: You're welcome Craig. Spencer makes an excellent point about the Date function, so if you can get it to run the literal comparison without the date() function in the ON statement, it should be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you are needing to accomplish. Example data and example output would go a long ways towards clearing that up. Setting up a SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com might help you get an answer faster.

I suspect that the issue is with the predicate on shift_date in the `WHERE` clause.

It sounds like the result you are after could be produced by an "anti-join" pattern. That starts as an outer join, in this case, return all rows from `users` along with matching rows from `shifts`.

```
SELECT u.user_id
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN shifts s
    ON s.user_id = u.user_id
```

In this case, you want to find matching shifts starting on a given date...

```
   AND s.shift_start >= '2016-03-16'
   AND s.shift_start <  '2016-03-16' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

"But wait", you say, "those are the rows I don't want."

Right.

But it's an outer join, so we are getting *all* rows from `users`. If there are any matching rows in `shifts`, we get those rows too. For any rows in `users` that *don't* have a matching rows (meeting our specified criteria in the `ON` clause), the values of the columns from `shifts` will be NULL.

The trick is to *exclude* the rows that had a match. Any real rows from `shifts` will have non-null values in `shift_start`. (We're guaranteed that, because of the condition in the `ON` clause. A NULL value of `shift_start` wouldn't satisfy the condition.) So, we only want to return the rows that have a NULL value for `shift_start`. And adding a WHERE clause with that condition is pretty easy:

```
 WHERE s.shift_start IS NULL
```

Any user with a matching row in shifts will *not* be returned. And so what we get back is just the users that *don't* have a shift starting on the specified date.

Putting that all together:

```
SELECT u.user_id
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN shifts s
    ON s.user_id = u.user_id
   AND s.shift_start >= '2016-03-16'
   AND s.shift_start <  '2016-03-16' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 WHERE s.shift_start IS NULL
```

And obviously, this isn't the only query pattern that will return that result. We could use a query with a `NOT EXISTS` predicate to get an equivalent result.

The anti-join pattern is a bit much to get your brain wrapped around. But once you master it, it's a powerful tool to keep in the SQL toolbelt.

I've omitted the other tables for the sake of clarity. I'm expecting you will be able to fill out the select list, add in joins to the additional tables, add the `GROUP BY`, and so on, to build the actual set you need.

```
   AND u.user_owner = 2 
   AND u.user_level= 'Personnel' 
   AND u.user_active = 1
```

If this isn't the result you were looking for, then I misunderstood the specification. Example data and the expected output would go a long ways to helping me understand the specification.

Comment: Thanks so much for the completeness of your answer spencer, that's been a lesson for me.  Took me a few reads to wrap my head around but I think I get it and it will come in really handy.  Really appreciate it and apologies if the question was a bit vague.

Comment: My goal isn't to just solve your immediate problem (that's important), but I don't want to write SQL you don't understand. I think it's important that an answer *explain* why the SQL is written the way it's written, and that you come away with the kind of understanding that will enable you to apply the same pattern to similar problems. The "anti-join" patter is a powerful tool to have in your SQL toolbelt. It's not always the right tool for every job, but it sometimes is exactly the tool you need to get a job done.

Comment: There's a specific reason I replaced the **`DATE(col) = literal`** with a different pattern. With that function wrapped around the column, that forces MySQL to evaluate that function on *every* row in the table (that satisfies the other criteria), and the compare the return from that function with a literal.  When we instead write **`col >= literal AND col < literal`**, then we allow MySQL to perform a range scan operation on an appropriate index. And that can improve performance dramatically, by allowing MySQL to eliminate vast swaths of rows from consideration, without even looking at them

Comment: Thanks again!  I have a very limited dataset at the moment since everything's in dev so just enough for testing, but even then there's a measurable difference in the execution time using the range. Small consolation, but I've upvoted your answer in thanks.

Comment: If suitable indexes are available, an appropriate range scan operation for a small subset of rows is going to blow the socks off a full table scan. The difference isn't noticeable with small sets, but we get into the millions of rows, it gets very noticeable. It sounds like you are on track. Good luck.